# ¿Por qué no me lee el archivo plano con ArrayList (JAVA)?

Tags: java, archivo, arraylist, netbeans-8.2

El archivo plano escribe porque se va guardando la informacion en el txt, pero no hace la lectura correctamente y esto hace que no pueda ver la cantidad de Prendas que al final pongo en un ciclo. En este caso estoy probando con Indumentaria.

```
public class Taller2 {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



        ArrayList<Indumentaria> ind1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Calzado> cal1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Accesorio> acc1 = new ArrayList<>();

        String cortarString[] = {"Camisetafresca", "XL",
            "Air Max", "Hombre", "Nike", "Azul oscuro", "Poliester",
            "96", "10990"};

        ind1.add(new Indumentaria(cortarString[0], cortarString[1],
                cortarString[2], cortarString[3], cortarString[4],
                cortarString[5], cortarString[6],
                Integer.parseInt(cortarString[7]), Integer.parseInt(cortarString[8])));

        ind1.add(new Indumentaria("loca", "dsad", "fdsaf", "gdfsg", "empanda",
                "diomedes", "morcilla", (int) 45, (int) 4));

        int op;
        String menu = "MENU"
                + "\n\n1. Crear nueva indumentaria. "

                + "\n4. Eliminar prenda."
                + "\n5. Modificar datos."
                + "\n6. Almacenar base de datos."
                + "\n7. Tamaños."
                + "\n0. Salir. ";

        do {
            op = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu));

            switch (op) {
                case 1:
                    String tipoIndumentaria = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tipo indumentaria: ");
                    String talla = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Talla: ");
                    String nombrePrenda = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre de la prenda");
                    String genero = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Genero: ");
                    String marca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Marca: ");
                    String color = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Color: ");
                    String material = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Material");
                    int stock = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Stock: "));
                    int precio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Precio: "));


                    ind1.add(new Indumentaria(tipoIndumentaria, talla,
                            nombrePrenda, genero, marca, color, material,
                            (int) stock, (int)  precio));

                    break;



                case 4:
                    int op2;
                    op2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. "
                            + "Indumentaria \n2. Calzado \n3. Accesorio \n"));

                    switch (op2) {
                        case 1:
                            String eliminar;
                            eliminar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nombre de indumentaria a eliminar: ");

                            for (int i = 0; i < ind1.size(); i++) {
                                if (ind1.get(i).getNombrePrenda().equalsIgnoreCase(eliminar)) {
                                    ind1.remove(i);
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha eliminado.");
                                    eliminar = "";
                                    RA.escribirArchivo(ind1);

                                }

                            }
                            if (!eliminar.equals("")) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha encontrado la indumentaria.");
                            }

                            break;


                        case 5:
                            int op3;
                            op3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. "
                                    + "Indumentaria \n2. Calzado \n3. Accesorio \n"));

                            switch (op3) {
                                case 1:
                                    String modi;
                                    int modi2;
                                    modi = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nombre de indumentaria a modificar: ");

                                    for (int i = 0; i < ind1.size(); i++) {
                                        if (ind1.get(i).getNombrePrenda().equalsIgnoreCase(modi)) {
                                            modi2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Que desea modificar: \n"
                                                    + "1. Tipo indumentaria"
                                                    + "2. Talla"
                                                    + "3. Nombre prenda"
                                                    + "4. Genero"
                                                    + "5. Marca"
                                                    + "6. Color"
                                                    + "7. Material"
                                                    + "8. Stock"
                                                    + "9. Precio"
                                                    + "10. Nombre ciudad"));

                                            switch (modi2) {
                                                case 1:
                                                    tipoIndumentaria = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Tipo indumentaria: ");
                                                    ind1.get(i).setTipoIndumentaria(tipoIndumentaria);
                                                    break;
                                                case 2:
                                                    talla = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Talla: ");
                                                    ind1.get(i).setTalla(talla);
                                                    break;
                                                case 3:
                                                    nombrePrenda = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre prenda: ");
                                                    ind1.get(i).setNombrePrenda(nombrePrenda);
                                                    break;
                                                case 4:
                                                    genero = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Genero: ");
                                                    ind1.get(i).setGenero(genero);
                                                    break;
                                                case 5:
                                                    marca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Marca: ");
                                                    ind1.get(i).setMarca(marca);
                                                    break;
                                                case 6:
                                                    color = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Color: ");
                                                    ind1.get(i).setColor(color);

                                                    break;
                                                case 7:
                                                    material = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Material: ");
                                                    ind1.get(i).setMaterial(material);

                                                    break;
                                                case 8:
                                                    stock = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Stock: "));
                                                    ind1.get(i).setStock(stock);

                                                    break;
                                                case 9:
                                                    precio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Precio: "));
                                                    ind1.get(i).setPrecio(precio);

                                                    break;


                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (!modi.equals("")) {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha encontrado la prenda.");
                                    }

                                    break;



                                default:
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese nombre de indumentaria valida");

                                    break;




                case 7:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hay en total " + ind1.size() + " indumentarias");


                    break;

                case 0:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Guardando.");

                    break;

                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese opcion valida");

                    break;

            }
            //RA.crear();          
            RA.escribirArchivo(ind1);
            ind1 = RA.leerArchivo();

            System.out.println(" ------------PRENDAS-------- ");
            for (int i = 0; i < ind1.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Tipo indumentaria.........: "
                        + ind1.get(i).getTipoIndumentaria());

                System.out.println("Talla.........: "
                        + ind1.get(i).getTalla());

                System.out.println("Nombre PRENDA.........: "
                        + ind1.get(i).getNombrePrenda());

                System.out.println("Genero.........: "
                        + ind1.get(i).getGenero());

                System.out.println("Marca.........: "
                        + ind1.get(i).getMarca());

                System.out.println("Color.........: "
                        + ind1.get(i).getColor());

                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            }
                    System.out.println("HAY EN TOTAL: " + ind1.size() + " PRENDAS");

        } while (op != 0);

    }

}
```

Adjunto ahora la clase donde escribo y leo el archivo

```
public class RA { 

public static void crear() throws IOException { //Este metodo no hace falta
    File f = new File("IndumentariasRA.txt");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.createNewFile();
        System.out.println(f.getName() + " Ha sido creado.");
    }
    System.out.println("Ruta: " + f.getPath());
    System.out.println("Ruta absoluta: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Ultima modificacion: " + f.lastModified());
    System.out.println("Tamaño: " + f.length());
}

public static void escribirArchivo(ArrayList<Indumentaria> ind1) {
    try {
        File f = new File("IndumentariasRA.txt");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            for (int i = 0; i < ind1.size(); i++) {
                pw.println(ind1.get(i));
            }
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fw.close();
        } else if (f.exists()) {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            for (int i = 0; i < ind1.size(); i++) {
                pw.println(ind1.get(i));
            }
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fw.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error de escritura en el"
                + " archivo plano indumentarias");
    }

}//Escribir Archivo Plano

public static ArrayList<Indumentaria> leerArchivo() {
    File f;
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br;
    String linea;
    ArrayList<Indumentaria> ind1 = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        f = new File("IndumentariasRA.txt");
        fr = new FileReader(f);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while (((linea = br.readLine()) != null)) {
            String cortarString[] = linea.split(",");
            Indumentaria indumentaria = new Indumentaria(cortarString[0], cortarString[1], cortarString[2], cortarString[3], cortarString[4], cortarString[5], cortarString[6], Integer.parseInt(cortarString[7]), Integer.parseInt(cortarString[8]));
            ind1.add(indumentaria);

        }//while
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo leer el "
                + "archivo plano indumentarias");
    }//FIN LECTURA
    return ind1;
}
```

Esta es la clase indumentaria

```
    public class Indumentaria extends Prenda
{
    private String tipoIndumentaria;
    private String talla;

    public Indumentaria(String tipoIndumentaria, String talla, String nombrePrenda, String genero, String marca, String color, String material, int stock, int precio)
    {
        super(nombrePrenda, genero, marca, color, material, stock, precio);
        this.tipoIndumentaria = tipoIndumentaria;
        this.talla = talla;
    }



    public String getTipoIndumentaria() 
    {
        return tipoIndumentaria;
    }

    public void setTipoIndumentaria(String tipoIndumentaria) 
    {
        this.tipoIndumentaria = tipoIndumentaria;
    }

    public String getTalla() 
    {
        return talla;
    }

    public void setTalla(String talla)
    {
        this.talla = talla;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCodigo()
    {
        return 98745;

    }

    @Override
    public String getReferencia()
    {
        return "IND98745";      
    }



    @Override
    public double obtenerValorDescuento()
    {
        return (getPrecio()*0.15);       
    }

    @Override
    public double porcentajeDescuento() 
    {
        return 15;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return 
                super.toString()+","+getTipoIndumentaria()+","+getCodigo()+","+getReferencia()+","+getTalla();//+","+obtenerValorDescuento()+","+porcentajeDescuento();
    }


}
```

Ahora la clase "Prenda" que es la superclase

```
public abstract class Prenda implements ITiendaRopa
```

{
    private String nombrePrenda;
    private String genero;
    private String marca;
    private String color;
    private String material;
    private int stock;
    private int precio;

```
//private Ciudad ciudad;

public Prenda(String nombrePrenda, String genero, String marca, String color, String material, int stock, int precio /*Ciudad ciudad*/) {
    this.nombrePrenda = nombrePrenda;
    this.genero = genero;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.color = color;
    this.material = material;
    this.stock = stock;
    this.precio = precio;
    //this.ciudad = ciudad;
}



public String getNombrePrenda() 
{
    return nombrePrenda;
}

public void setNombrePrenda(String nombrePrenda)
{
    this.nombrePrenda = nombrePrenda;
}

public String getGenero()
{
    return genero;
}

public void setGenero(String genero)
{
    this.genero = genero;
}

public String getMarca()
{
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca)
{
    this.marca = marca;
}

public String getColor()
{
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color)
{
    this.color = color;
}

public String getMaterial() 
{
    return material;
}

public void setMaterial(String material)
{
    this.material = material;
}

public int getStock()
{
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(int stock)
{
    this.stock = stock;
}

public int getPrecio()
{
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(int precio) 
{
    this.precio = precio;
}
```

//    public Ciudad getCiudad() 
//    {
//        return ciudad;
//    }
//
//    public void setCiudad(Ciudad ciudad) 
//    {
//        this.ciudad = ciudad;
//    }

```
@Override
public int getCodigo() 
{
    return 0;//No retorna nada porque de Prenda no se pueden crear objetos
}

@Override
public String getReferencia()
{
    return "";//No retorna nada porque de Prenda no se pueden crear objetos
}



public abstract double obtenerValorDescuento();
public abstract double porcentajeDescuento();

@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return 

              getNombrePrenda()+","+getGenero()+","+getMarca()+","+getColor()+","+getMaterial()+","+getStock()+","+getPrecio();


}
```

}

Aparece este error

> run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "Camisetafresca"    at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   taller2.RA.leerArchivo(RA.java:70)    at
>   taller2.Taller2.main(Taller2.java:510) C:\Users\Juan Pablo
>   Rivera\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 31 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas realizando una conversión a Integer de caracteres que no son numéricos, en este caso la cadena "Camisetafresca".

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Camisetafresca"

eso sucede en esta linea:

```
Indumentaria indumentaria = new Indumentaria(cortarString[0], cortarString[1], cortarString[2], cortarString[3], cortarString[4], cortarString[5], cortarString[6], Integer.parseInt(cortarString[7]), Integer.parseInt(cortarString[8]));
```

Te sugiero como opción usar este método el cual asignara 0 como valor default en caso de que el carácter no sea numérico:

```
public static int obtieneValorNumerico(String number){
    int result = 0;
    try{
        if(number != null){
            result = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

y lo uses de esta forma en la línea de código que produce el error:

```
Indumentaria indumentaria = new Indumentaria(cortarString[0], cortarString[1], cortarString[2], cortarString[3], cortarString[4], cortarString[5], cortarString[6], obtieneValorNumerico(cortarString[7]), obtieneValorNumerico(cortarString[8]));
```

El método `obtieneValorNumerico()` realizará lo mismo que `Integer.parseInt()` pero en el caso de marcar error regresara un valor 0 que evitaría el problema.

---

**Actualización:** Al revisar el código se encuentran varias llamadas a la clase Indumentaria, por lo tanto en este caso lo correcto es validar los valores recibidos en la clase.

```
public class Indumentaria extends Prenda
{
    private String tipoIndumentaria;
    private String talla;

    public Indumentaria(String tipoIndumentaria, String talla, String nombrePrenda, String genero, String marca, String color, String material, int stock, int precio)
    {      
        super(nombrePrenda, genero, marca, color, material, obtieneValorNumerico(stock), obtieneValorNumerico(precio));
        this.tipoIndumentaria = tipoIndumentaria;
        this.talla = talla;
    }

    public static int obtieneValorNumerico(String number){
       int result = 0;
       try{
           if(number != null){
               result = Integer.parseInt(number);
           }
       }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
           nfe.printStackTrace();
       }
       return result;
    }


    public String getTipoIndumentaria() 
    {
        return tipoIndumentaria;
    }

    public void setTipoIndumentaria(String tipoIndumentaria) 
    {
        this.tipoIndumentaria = tipoIndumentaria;
    }

    public String getTalla() 
    {
        return talla;
    }

    public void setTalla(String talla)
    {
        this.talla = talla;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCodigo()
    {
        return 98745;

    }

    @Override
    public String getReferencia()
    {
        return "IND98745";      
    }



    @Override
    public double obtenerValorDescuento()
    {
        return (getPrecio()*0.15);       
    }

    @Override
    public double porcentajeDescuento() 
    {
        return 15;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return 
                super.toString()+","+getTipoIndumentaria()+","+getCodigo()+","+getReferencia()+","+getTalla();//+","+obtenerValorDescuento()+","+porcentajeDescuento();
    }


}
```

Comment: Lo probaré amigo, gracias.

Comment: @JuanPabloRivera Prueba y comenta que resultados obtienes, saludos!

Comment: Claro que si, una pregunta, en el metodo principal tambien hago esta correcion?

Comment: @JuanPabloRivera acabo de ver que tienes el mismo problema en varias partes de tu código, agrega la clase Indumentaria, lo mejor sería validar en este método que estar validando en todos los puntos donde instancias esta clase..

Comment: Ok, la agregare

Comment: Ya ejecuta y muestra algunos datoos del ciclo, pero sigue mostrando errores como: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Camisetafresca" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) at taller2.RA.obtieneValorNumerico(RA.java:22)

Comment: Solo realiza la modificación en la clase Indumentaria. @JuanPabloRivera

Comment: Y como realizo esa validacion en esa clase?

Comment: @JuanPabloRivera te agregue la clase modificada en mi respuesta. :P

Comment: Listo, muestra el ciclo pero muestra tambien varios errores, antes del ciclo muestra esto java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Camisetafresca", y despues de que se muestran los datos, algunos como por ejemplo  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65), at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at taller2.Indumentaria.obtieneValorNumerico(Indumentaria.java:25)
 at taller2.RA.leerArchivo(RA.java:88)
 at taller2.Taller2.main(Taller2.java:521)

Comment: ya todo me da, solo me salta un error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at taller2.RA.leerArchivo(RA.java:90)
 at taller2.Taller2.main(Taller2.java:518) AYUDAME POR FAVOR

Comment: @JuanPabloRivera indicame cual es esa linea por favor.

Comment: Es la linea que tiene la correccion que indicaste, la que producia el error

Comment: @JuanPabloRivera **este es un error diferente al definido en la pregunta original** , en este caso debes asegurar que el array cortarString contiene los 9 elementos requeridos.